# what has priority HTACCESS or Magento or?

Tags: magento-1.9, https

My question is if i setup security using the Magento admin panel and turn on the Secure settings, will the HTACCESS file override the Magento setting when using HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically - yes, if you will force your magento instance by setting up in your .htaccess file redirect https to http - it will probably cause error (endless loop).